# Any changes to Facebook Connect recently - asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, facebook

We have had the facebook connect register/login working on our site successfully until recently. But it is now broken, we were getting a error about "perms needs to be changed to scope", so I did that but now I can't seem  to get any information from the cookies.

Here is the orginal code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    FB.init({
        appId: '<%= Web.AppSettings.FacebookApiId() %>', cookie: true,
        status: true, xfbml: true
    });
</script>
<fb:login-button perms="email,user_birthday,user_location"   onlogin='window.location="/default.aspx?fb=1"'>Login with Facebook</fb:login-button>
```

Then to check the authorisation use:

```
var auth = new CanvasAuthorizer { Permissions = new[] { "email", "user_birthday", "user_location" } };
auth.Authorize()
```

Comment: What is the version of your C# SDK?

Answer (score 0):

The breaking change you are referring to was known as the OAuth 2.0 migration, as seen on the [Facebook Developer Roadmap](https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/).

I would pull down the latest version of the SDK you are using or switch to [this one](http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com/).

Facebook is constantly breaking things and changing their API - in fact its what they are known for and is partially why there is an entire facebook.stackoverflow.com site.  Also, they accept 2 to 3 times the number of new bugs than the bugs they fix each week so I'm sure you will run into plenty more!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you keep track of the following facebook blogs for all the developer announcements. Facebook also recommends the same. Facebook app development is a dynamic ongoing process, something is gonna change sometime.

http://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/ 
http://developers.facebook.com/blog/